# Displaying HTML instead of Onclick

Tags: html

I found a script online that shows the nearest location based on geolocation.  The user has to press a button though to see the Phone number.  How do I display the phone number on page load without a button click?

````
<button onclick="getLocation()">Click this button to get nearest office to you.</button>
<p id="phonenumber"></p>
<script>
//Element to put phone number for closest Marketo office to user
var x = document.getElementById("phonenumber");

//Coordinates for Marketo offices
var officeLocations = {
    "San Mateo": {latitude: 37.5596465, longitude: -122.2870142},
    "Atlanta": {latitude: 33.8547013, longitude: -84.35552349999999},
    "Tokyo": {latitude: 35.6895, longitude: 139.6917},
    "Dublin": {latitude: 53.3478, longitude: -6.2603097},
    "Sydney": {latitude: -33.873651, longitude: 151.2068896},
    "Portland": {latitude: 45.512089, longitude: -122.6763367},
    "Tel Aviv": {latitude: 32.0852999, longitude: 34.78176759999999}
}

//Phone numbers for Marketo offices
var officePhoneNumbers = {
    "San Mateo": "+1-650-376-2300",
    "Atlanta": "+1-877-260-6586",
    "Tokyo": "+81-03-6759-8280",
    "Dublin": "+353-1-242-3000",
    "Sydney": "+61-2-9045-2711",
    "Portland": "+1-877-260-6586",
    "Tel Aviv": "+1-877-260-6586"
}

//Method to get user's current location. Returns a position object with user's geo coordinates
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(findNearestOffice);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Marketo Location: San Mateo<br>Marketo Phone Number: +1-877-260-6586";
    }
}

//Find nearest Marketo office to user's location
function findNearestOffice(position) {
        var nearestOffice = geolib.findNearest({latitude: position.coords.latitude, longitude: position.coords.longitude}, officeLocations);
        x.innerHTML = "Marketo Location: " + nearestOffice.key + "<br>Marketo Phone Number: " +  officePhoneNumbers[nearestOffice.key];
}
</script>```
````

Comment: Have you tried using the onload event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At present, you have a button with an associated `onclick` event that runs the  `getLocation()` function. If you want the function to run on page load, you need to associate the function what that event.

To do this, you want code something like this in your script block:

```js
window.onload = function getLocation() {
  CODE
};
```

Alternatively, you could add an `onload` event to your `body` tag and associate it with the same function as the current button `onclick`.